# Function to return object's property

Tags: swift

I'd like to change an object's parameter, but I like to decide later about what's the parameter that should change. I'm thinking to make a function for that, but don't know how. Here's a sample:

```
class Car {
    var color = "green"
    var brand = "Zastava"
    var mechanic = "Mark Gaia"
}

struct Change {
    var property: String
    var newValue: String
}

let car = Car()
let change = Change(property: "brand", newValue: "Fiat")
car.propertyFromChange(change) = change.newValue  // ??? How to implement this line
```

How to make a function that returns what's the parameter of an object that needs to be changed?
Alternatively, how to choose which parameter to change?
(...I thought about `switch` statement. Is a good direction?)

I'm pretty sure that's something that has already been discussed on internet. I've read everything about functions and couldn't find the solution, so I guess I'm searching using wrong keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a function you can use KVC like this after you inherit from `NSObject`, or you can make a new func that guards again bad property names.

```
class Car: NSObject {
    var color = "green"
    var brand = "Zastava"
    var mechanic = "Mark Gaia"
}

struct Change {
    var property: String
    var newValue: String
}

let car = Car()
let change = Change(property: "brand", newValue: "Fiat")
car.setValue(change.newValue, forKey: change.property)
```

Keep in mind that this code will crash if you enter bad property names.

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of KVC `setValue(value: AnyObject?, forKey key: String)` method by making `Car` a subclass of `NSObject`.

```
class Car: NSObject {
  var color = "green"
  var brand = "Zastava"
  var mechanic = "Mark Gaia"
}

struct Change {
  var property: String
  var newValue: String
}

let car = Car()
let change = Change(property: "brand", newValue: "Fiat")

car.setValue(change.newValue, forKey: change.property)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `Car`inherits from `NSObject` you get key-value-coding for free and can change the value with `setValue:forKey`

```
class Car : NSObject {
  var color = "green"
  var brand = "Zastava"
  var mechanic = "Mark Gaia"
}

struct Change {
  var property: String
  var newValue: String
}

let car = Car()
let change = Change(property: "brand", newValue: "Fiat")
car.setValue(change.newValue, forKey: change.property)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your approach a bit by doing this

If you store all your properties in the struct itself, you wouldnt need to worry about that at all.

:) Hope this helps

```
    struct CarProperties {
    var color : String = ""
    var brand : String = ""
    var mechanic : String = ""
}
class Car {
    var carProperties = CarProperties()
}

let car = Car()
car.carProperties.color = "Green"
car.carProperties.brand = "yourFavBrand"
car.carProperties.mechanic = "whatever"

let change = "this"

// Suppose you want to change the  brand
car.carProperties.brand = change

print(car.carProperties.brand)
```